# My ArrayList data is not destroyed when creating new instance of a class

Tags: java, android, dom, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am running three `AsyncTask()` each `AsyncTask` create an object of another class.

This is how i am creating instance of a class from `doInBackground()`,

```
        DOM domObject = new DOM;
```

Now, there is a class level `ArrayList` in my `DOM` class,

```
public class DOM {
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> tempNewsArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

My main class run three `AysncTask` object so three separate instance of `DOM` class should be created for each `AsyncTask`.

On each execution of `AsyncTask`, some data is added into the `ArrayList`.

Example,
First `AsynTask` executed,
   Some Data added in `ArrayList`.
Second `AsyncTask` executed,
   Some Data added in `ArrayList` (Previous Data should not be there in `ArrayList`)

But the problem is, the data from the previous instance of `DOM` class is still there in the `ArrayList` and not removed when new instance of `DOM` class is created by another `AysnTask` instace.

Why is this happening ?

Example,
First instance of `DOM` class created by first `Asynctask`,
Some data is added in ArrayList.

Second instance of `DOM` class is created by second `Asynctask` instance,
Some new data is added in the `ArrayList` but the previous data from previous instances is still there.

Why so ?

Comment: The `tempNewsArray` is `static` which means that all instances of `DOM` use the same `tempNewsArray`

Comment: but if i do like this, `public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> tempNewsArray` and then create the instance of it inside another method like this, `new ArrayList<>();` then the data from previous `DOM` instance are not there. Why this behavior since the `ArrayList` is still `static`.

Answer (score 2):

`tempNewsArray` is static, so all `Dom` isntances share a single copy of that member, which is initialized just once, when the `Dom` class is initialized.

If you wish each `Dom` instance to have its own ArrayList member, change its declaration to :

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> tempNewsArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: but if i do like this, `public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> tempNewsArray` and then create the instance of it inside another method like this, `new ArrayList<>();` then the data from previous `DOM` instance are not there. Why this behavior since the `ArrayList` is still `static`.

Comment: @Joe If you overwrite the `tempNewsArray` reference by assigning to it a new ArrayList isntance, the old ArrayList object is no longer referred by that static variable, but it doesn't change the fact that there is only one `tempNewsArray` member shared by all instances. When you initialize the static member in a static initialization expression (or in a static initializer block), it will be initialized just once.